# Add 5 columns of data under another data set - Next Blank Row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to put two different data sets together and it isn't working for me. Here is the code.

```
Sheets("Event Data").Select
    Range("S:S,T:T,U:U,AA:AA,N:N").Select
    Range("Table_Query_from_PostgreSQL35W[[#Headers],[site_name]]").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Staff List").Select
    Range("A1:E1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

 Sheets("Anon").Select
    Range("A:A,D:D,O:O,P:P,Q:Q").Select
    Range("P2").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Staff List").Select
    **Range("A2:E2").Select**
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

I know this is not correct. The issue I am having is selecting the first blank row (which I can do for one row) but for multiple rows (A:E). I am looking for a solution quickly. Thank you.

Comment: I did a horrible job explaining this. Ill try again. The first data set, the top set of code or 'Event Data' data, is currently 467 rows long, but will grow. I want the second data set, the data from 'Anon', to go on the 'Staff List' sheet directly after the 'Event Data' data.

Answer (score 1):

For the next blank row in any of A:E try,

```
dim nr as long
with workSheets("Staff List")
  nr = application.max(.cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup).offset(1, 0).row, _
                       .cells(.rows.count, "B").end(xlup).offset(1, 0).row, _
                       .cells(.rows.count, "C").end(xlup).offset(1, 0).row, _
                       .cells(.rows.count, "D").end(xlup).offset(1, 0).row, _
                       .cells(.rows.count, "E").end(xlup).offset(1, 0).row)
  .cells(nr, "A").paste
end with
```

The above code replaces the following lines of code:

```
Sheets("Staff List").Select
**Range("A2:E2").Select**
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: So where/how would I use?

Comment: I get a syntax error as soon as I put it in. "Expected end of statement"

Comment: Apparently I somehow double-typed a closing bracket; you probably should have been able to figure that out.

Comment: Does anyone else have a fix for my issue?